# Reset Password Link Not Sent

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase relying on Flutter, and I have written a code for a user to request a reset password link to be sent via e-mail.

The only problem is that the e-mail isn't be received, which probably means that it isn't being sent.

Why isn't the e-mail being sent?

My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:choice_hi/widgets/my_textfield2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

class PasswordRequest extends StatelessWidget {

  final _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  TextEditingController fieldTextControl = TextEditingController();
  String? enteredText;

  PasswordRequest({super.key});

  Future<void> newPasswordLink() async {
    await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: fieldTextControl.text.trim());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Request Password Link'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: MyTextField2(
                  obscureText: false,
                  hintText: 'Enter your e-mail address here',
                  controller: fieldTextControl,
                  maxWidth: 320.0,
                  maxHeight: 44.0,
                  inputTextSize: 19.0,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                onChanged: (value) {
                    enteredText = value;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Submit Request'),
                onPressed: newPasswordLink),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result I get is that Flutter confirms the entered e-mail address:

> I/FirebaseAuth(19431): Password reset request stacks@example.com with empty reCAPTCHA token

But no e-mail is sent/received.  Inbox and junk checked, and that's an example address - I tried with a real e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange one because after watching a tutorial on this, I changed my code by adding a try-catch and also alert-dialogs, and after doing these things, when I tried for the e-mail link it was sent and received.

Comment: same problem, any future progress? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this was resolved by wrapping the "await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: fieldTextControl.text.trim());" call with a try/catch block.  For some reason that made a positive difference at the time.

Comment: I already had the try/catch but still got the "I/FirebaseAuth( ): Password reset request test@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token"

Comment: In that case, the causing issues aren't the same.  Study [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWamixHIKmQ) and this [tutorial too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wtrow-yzjf8), and compare directions with what you've done, and you'll either discover a step you've missed, or an alternative way to the outcome.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks, I already reported a bug and await a response. Because "signing", "signout" and "register" a user is OK, only the "sendPasswordResetEmail" encounters problems.

Comment: Okay, understood.  Another thing you could do is draft a question for Stack and tag it with firebase and firebase-authentication, showing your code and how your current position could be replicated.  That will get the attention of the official Firebase team who may respond with a solution.

Comment: OK, thanks. Finally, I found the password reset request email in the spam. Looks like the "Password reset request with empty reCAPTCHA token" is fine.

Comment: LOL, now that's something I really didn't think of : )  Well done for resolving and moving on to the next stage.